# Regex for IP address with last part non-zero

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

This is my regex for IP address. How can I modify it to exclude a 0 (ZERO) in the last part.

`^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$`

Example:

148.23.54.20 //valid

148.23.54.0 //Invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your number does not **start** with a zero...

```
[1-9]\d?
```

So, for example, your regex would end with

```
\.([1-9]|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

This will allow 1 to 255.

*The extra escapes were left out for clarity.*

## Sidenote

For your other 3 cases that that **can** be 0, simply add an option for only 0

```
\.(0|[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Only special handle the last part

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

Comment: Although this works, it allows the last part of IP with preceding ZEROs which is not valid in an IP.

Answer (score -1):

How about a non regex solution:

```
String ip = /* some ip */;
String[] bytes = ip.split("\\.");
if (!bytes[3].equals("0") && Arrays.stream(bytes).map(Integer::parseInt).allMatch(i -> i >= 0 && i < 256)) {
    //Valid ip
}
```

You can check for `IntegerParseException` and do some bounds checks if you're expecting some crazy input, as well. I believe this is a lot more readable and thus maintainable for that sake